# Compiling PJSUA for android error: undefined references

Tags: android, android-ndk, sip, pjsip

Hello I am trying to compile pjsua for android video calling. After following steps on [pjusa](http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Android#pjsua) I am getting following errors.

```
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:1253: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_conf_disconnect'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:1277: error: undefined reference to 'pj_strncpy_with_null'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:1279: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_conf_adjust_rx_level'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:1291: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_conf_adjust_tx_level'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:1314: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_codec_set_priority'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:1318: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_vid_codec_set_priority'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:1333: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_get_state'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:1335: error: undefined reference to 'pj_cli_get_cmd_id'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:1353: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_snd_get_setting'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:1356: error: undefined reference to 'pj_perror_2'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:1370: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_snd_set_setting'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:1372: error: undefined reference to 'pj_perror_4'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:1383: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_dump'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:1394: error: undefined reference to 'pj_log_1'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:1414: error: undefined reference to 'pj_log_1'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:1419: error: undefined reference to 'pj_file_open'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:1425: error: undefined reference to 'pj_file_write'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:1426: error: undefined reference to 'pj_file_close'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:1443: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_get_state'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:1473: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_call_get_count'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:1491: error: undefined reference to 'pj_strncpy'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:1498: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_msg_data_init'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:1500: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_call_make_call'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:1514: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_call_get_count'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:1536: error: undefined reference to 'pj_strncpy'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:1544: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_call_make_call'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:1583: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_msg_data_init'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:1594: error: undefined reference to 'pjsip_generic_string_hdr_init2'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:1610: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_call_answer2'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:1623: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_call_hangup_all'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:1625: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_call_hangup'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:1634: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_call_set_hold'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:1650: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_call_reinvite2'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:1662: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_call_update2'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:1732: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_msg_data_init'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:1735: error: undefined reference to 'pjsip_generic_string_hdr_init2'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:1748: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_call_xfer'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:1753: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_call_xfer'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:1778: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_enum_calls'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:1819: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_call_is_active'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:1828: error: undefined reference to 'pjsip_generic_string_hdr_init2'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:1833: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_call_xfer_replaces'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:1846: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_call_is_active'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:1856: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_call_process_redirect'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:1860: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_call_process_redirect'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:1863: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_call_process_redirect'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:1866: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_call_process_redirect'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:1880: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_call_has_media'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:1895: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_call_dial_dtmf'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:1941: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_call_send_request'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:1965: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_acc_get_count'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:2023: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_call_send_request'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:2032: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_call_get_count'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:2141: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_pool_create'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:2153: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_pool_create'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:2190: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_call_set_vid_strm'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:2201: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_call_vid_strm_op_param_default'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:2204: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_call_get_stream_info'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:2214: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_call_set_vid_strm'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:2229: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_call_vid_strm_op_param_default'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:2233: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_call_set_vid_strm'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:2244: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_call_vid_strm_op_param_default'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:2248: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_call_set_vid_strm'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:2255: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_call_vid_strm_op_param_default'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:2273: error: undefined reference to 'pjmedia_vid_dev_refresh'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:2285: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_vid_preview_param_default'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:2288: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_vid_preview_start'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:2289: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_vid_preview_get_win'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:2292: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_vid_preview_get_win'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:2296: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_vid_win_set_show'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:2297: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_vid_preview_stop'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:2307: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_vid_enum_codecs'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:2319: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_vid_codec_get_param'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:2323: error: undefined reference to 'pjmedia_format_get_video_format_detail'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:2342: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_vid_codec_set_priority'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:2357: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_vid_codec_get_param'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:2361: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_vid_codec_set_param'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:2377: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_vid_codec_get_param'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:2381: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_vid_codec_set_param'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:2401: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_vid_codec_set_param'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:2414: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_vid_enum_wins'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:2421: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_vid_win_get_info'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:2438: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_vid_win_set_show'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:2448: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_vid_win_set_pos'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:2458: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_vid_win_set_size'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:2552: error: undefined reference to 'pj_strtoul'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:2554: error: undefined reference to 'pj_thread_sleep'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:2566: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_detect_nat_type'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:2576: error: undefined reference to 'pj_cli_quit'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:2590: error: undefined reference to 'pj_throw_exception_'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:2610: error: undefined reference to 'pj_scan_init'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:2612: error: undefined reference to 'pj_push_exception_handler_'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:2617: error: undefined reference to 'pj_scan_get_until_chr'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:2623: error: undefined reference to 'pj_scan_fini'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:2626: error: undefined reference to 'pj_pop_exception_handler_'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:2640: error: undefined reference to 'pj_cli_quit'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:2736: error: undefined reference to 'pj_cli_add_cmd_from_xml'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:2792: error: undefined reference to 'pj_cli_add_cmd_from_xml'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:2837: error: undefined reference to 'pj_cli_add_cmd_from_xml'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_cli.c:2872: error: undefined reference to 'pj_cli_add_cmd_from_xml'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_common.c:52: error: undefined reference to 'pj_strtoul'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_common.c:55: error: undefined reference to 'pj_strtoul'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_common.c:57: error: undefined reference to 'pj_strtoul'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_common.c:69: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_call_get_max_count'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_common.c:71: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_call_is_active'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_common.c:78: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_call_is_active'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_common.c:92: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_call_get_max_count'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_common.c:125: error: undefined reference to 'pjsip_method_init_np'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_common.c:127: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_acc_create_request'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_common.c:129: error: undefined reference to 'pjsip_endpt_send_request'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_common.c:148: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_call_dump'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_common.c:151: error: undefined reference to 'pj_log_get_decor'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_common.c:152: error: undefined reference to 'pj_log_set_decor'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_common.c:154: error: undefined reference to 'pj_log_set_decor'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_common.c:170: error: undefined reference to 'pj_log_set_decor'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_common.c:245: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_vid_win_get_info'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_common.c:250: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_vid_win_set_pos'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_common.c:257: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_vid_win_set_pos'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_common.c:289: error: undefined reference to 'pjmedia_vid_dev_cap_name'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_common.c:301: error: undefined reference to 'pjmedia_get_video_format_info'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_common.c:323: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_vid_dev_count'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_common.c:331: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_vid_dev_get_info'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_common.c:336: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_vid_dev_get_info'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_common.c:342: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_vid_dev_get_info'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_config.c:219: error: undefined reference to 'pj_log_write'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_config.c:237: error: undefined reference to 'pj_pool_calloc'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_config.c:300: error: undefined reference to 'pj_pool_alloc'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_config.c:513: error: undefined reference to 'pj_getopt_long'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_config.c:562: error: undefined reference to 'pj_log_set_level'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_config.c:588: error: undefined reference to 'pj_log_set_color'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_config.c:589: error: undefined reference to 'pj_log_set_color'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_config.c:590: error: undefined reference to 'pj_log_set_color'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_config.c:591: error: undefined reference to 'pj_log_set_color'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_config.c:607: error: undefined reference to 'pj_dump_config'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_config.c:682: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_verify_sip_url'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_config.c:692: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_verify_sip_url'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_config.c:702: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_verify_sip_url'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_config.c:776: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_verify_url'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_config.c:786: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_verify_sip_url'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_config.c:790: error: undefined reference to 'pj_optind'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_config.c:790: error: undefined reference to 'pj_optarg'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_config.c:790: error: undefined reference to 'pjsip_use_compact_form'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_config.c:790: error: undefined reference to 'pjsip_include_allow_hdr_in_dlg'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_config.c:790: error: undefined reference to 'pjmedia_add_rtpmap_for_static_pt'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_config.c:790: error: undefined reference to 'pj_optarg'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_config.c:899: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_verify_url'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_config.c:1047: error: undefined reference to 'pj_rand'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_config.c:539: error: undefined reference to 'pj_getopt_long'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_config.c:1366: error: undefined reference to 'pj_stricmp'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_config.c:1425: error: undefined reference to 'pj_optarg'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_config.c:1425: error: undefined reference to 'pj_optind'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_config.c:1434: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_config_default'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_config.c:1435: error: undefined reference to 'pj_get_version'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_config.c:1436: error: undefined reference to 'pj_get_sys_info'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_config.c:1437: error: undefined reference to 'pj_strdup2_with_null'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_config.c:1439: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_logging_config_default'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_config.c:1440: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_media_config_default'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_config.c:1441: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_transport_config_default'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_config.c:1443: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_transport_config_default'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_config.c:1460: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_acc_config_default'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_config.c:1463: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_buddy_config_default'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_config.c:1528: error: undefined reference to 'pj_strcat2'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_config.c:1536: error: undefined reference to 'pj_strcat2'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_config.c:1544: error: undefined reference to 'pj_strcat2'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_config.c:1548: error: undefined reference to 'pj_strcat2'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_config.c:2070: error: undefined reference to 'pjsip_use_compact_form'
/home/neosoft/PJSUA/pjproject-2.4.5/pjlib/include/pj/list.h:128: error: undefined reference to 'pj_list_insert_before'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:53: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_enum_buddies'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:86: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_get_buddy_count'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:86: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_get_buddy_count'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:183: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_acc_get_info'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:218: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_enum_accs'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:375: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_call_get_stream_info'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:430: error: undefined reference to 'pjmedia_vid_dev_refresh'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:440: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_vid_preview_param_default'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:443: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_vid_preview_start'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:444: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_vid_preview_get_win'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:447: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_vid_preview_get_win'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:451: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_vid_win_set_show'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:452: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_vid_preview_stop'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:465: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_vid_enum_wins'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:482: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_vid_win_set_show'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:489: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_vid_win_set_pos'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:496: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_vid_win_set_size'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:512: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_vid_enum_codecs'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:528: error: undefined reference to 'pjmedia_format_get_video_format_detail'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:558: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_vid_codec_set_param'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:625: error: undefined reference to 'pj_strncpy'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:636: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_call_make_call'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:667: error: undefined reference to 'pj_strncpy'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:684: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_detect_nat_type'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:724: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_call_send_typing_ind'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:727: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_im_typing'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:737: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_call_send_typing_ind'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:740: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_im_typing'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:749: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_call_send_im'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:752: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_im_send'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:815: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_call_answer2'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:828: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_call_hangup_all'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:866: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_acc_is_valid'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:867: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_acc_set_default'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:894: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_buddy_add'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:918: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_acc_config_default'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:931: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_acc_add'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:947: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_buddy_is_valid'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:950: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_buddy_del'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:965: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_acc_is_valid'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:968: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_acc_del'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:976: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_call_set_hold'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:985: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_call_reinvite2'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:991: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_call_update2'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:1011: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_enum_codecs'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:1020: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_vid_enum_codecs'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:1058: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_codec_set_priority'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:1110: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_call_xfer'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:1116: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_call_xfer'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:1138: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_enum_calls'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:1200: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_call_xfer_replaces'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:1210: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_call_has_media'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:1230: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_call_dial_dtmf'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:1276: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_call_send_request'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:1293: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_acc_get_count'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:1342: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_call_send_request'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:1378: error: undefined reference to 'pj_thread_sleep'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:1393: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_buddy_subscribe_pres'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:1398: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_buddy_subscribe_pres'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:1414: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_acc_set_registration'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:1420: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_acc_set_registration'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:1513: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_acc_set_online_status2'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:1527: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_enum_conf_ports'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:1534: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_conf_get_port_info'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:1581: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_conf_disconnect'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:1598: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_conf_adjust_rx_level'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:1604: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_conf_adjust_tx_level'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:1642: error: undefined reference to 'pj_file_open'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:1647: error: undefined reference to 'pj_file_write'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:1648: error: undefined reference to 'pj_file_close'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:1660: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_dump'
../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:1730: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_call_setting_default'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [../bin/pjsua-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/neosoft/PJSUA/pjproject-2.4.5/pjsip-apps/build'
make: *** [pjsua-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi] Error 2
```

Stuck for a while on this issue. Any suggestions on this?

Comment: have you compiled `Pjsip` project before building samples?

Comment: @MustansarSaeed I did run ./configure command which generates build.mk then I tried compiling using ndk-build as suggested in docs. I am getting above errors!

Comment: You should build pjsip for Android so instead of `./configure`, you should execute command `./configure-android`, and there are also other paramters like TARGER_EABI etc. please check that also

Comment: yes I have done that part successfully. when I try to run ndk-build to build project I am getting above errors.

Comment: @MustansarSaeed i'm also unable to build pjsip, running  make dep && make clean && make produce following error logs. https://paste.ee/p/O64gr

Comment: You need link  the libraries, compile the pjsip, after this has been created the ".a" and and setup your makefile to link with the .a files that are in the lib from pjsip.

Answer (score 2):

Android ndk-path should be available in the `ANDROID_NDK_ROOT` environment variable.

Configure and compile pjsip with the desired `TARGET_ANDROID_API`, `arch` and `buildtype`:

```
$ NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=clang APP_PLATFORM=android-${TARGET_ANDROID_API} TARGET_ABI=$arch BUILD_TYPE=${buildtype} ./configure-android --use-ndk-cflags
$ make dep
$ make
```

Compile pjsua:

```
$ cd pjsip-apps/src/swig
$ make
```

libpjsua2.so will be created in `pjsip-apps/src/swig/java/android/libs/armeabi` directory.